# MS Teams AI Chat Bot App returns prompts "plan" instead of expected conversation

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-openai

I have an app based on [ChatGPT sample app](https://github.com/microsoft/sample-app-aoai-chatGPT/tree/main) working as expected with Azure Open AI subscription.

I'm trying to create an AI Chat Bot (Preview) app in MS Teams as well, expecting it to work the same way as afore mentioned ChatGPT app, but for some reason the responses it gives me back looking like some prompts plan no matter what I ask, i.e.:

> "You are not a human, but you can understand and respond to natural
> language queries. You can help people find information on a wide range
> of topics, from news and weather to sports scores and movie times. You
> can also provide directions, make reservations, and answer questions
> about products and services. Your goal is..."

I've played with the `config.json` and `skprompt.txt` settings as well to no avail.

Same settings work fine in Azure AI Studio playground.

My current settings are:

**config.json**

```json
{
  "schema": 1,
  "description": "AI Bot",
  "type": "completion",
  "completion": {
    "max_tokens": 200,
    "temperature": 0.9,
    "top_p": 0.0,
    "presence_penalty": 0.6,
    "frequency_penalty": 0.0
  }
}
```

**skprompt.txt**

```
You are an AI assistant that helps people find information.
```

I've double checked endpoint, model and API key settings and they seem to be correct as well.

The rest of `app.ts` file is as it comes with the template:

```js
import { MemoryStorage } from "botbuilder";
import * as path from "path";

import {
  Application,
  AzureOpenAIPlanner,
  DefaultPromptManager,
  OpenAIPlanner,
  OpenAIModerator,
} from "@microsoft/teams-ai";

import config from "./config";

// Create AI components
const planner = new AzureOpenAIPlanner({
  apiKey: config.azureOpenAIKey,
  endpoint: config.azureOpenAIEndpoint,
  defaultModel: "gpt3_5-some-custom-model-001",
  useSystemMessage: true,
  logRequests: true, 
  apiVersion: "2023-07-01-preview"
});

const promptManager = new DefaultPromptManager(path.join(__dirname, "../src/prompts"));

// Define storage and application
const storage = new MemoryStorage();
const app = new Application({
  storage,
  ai: {
    planner,
    promptManager,
    prompt: "chat",
    history: {
      assistantHistoryType: "text",
    },
  },
});

app.conversationUpdate("membersAdded", async (context) => {
  await context.sendActivity("How can I help you today?");
});

export default app;
```

Am I missing some fundamentals here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that for some reason the AI Chat Bot Preview template was missing a lot of code, when compared to [Teams Chef Bot template](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/blob/v2.3.0/teams-chef-bot/src/index.ts)'s `index.ts` file.

So I've simply copied missing bits over (couldn't get moderator to work though) and the AI chat bot started working in MS Teams as expected.